# Scaled object affects bake normal map

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

I’m trying to understand as why applied scale objects affect baked normal map. Here I’m baking a cone’s normal on to a plane. The cone scale has been applied, but applied scale on the plane produces the wrong cone normal. Why scale applied plane produces the wrong normal map? Thanks

[image: screenshots]

[blend file](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/k9zVKZd3u7AyDSLWB5lh9VKrNVB.blend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **cone is smooth-shaded and has no support edges**. This results in a "spherical" shading. When you use the matcap *Normal* in *Solid* mode then it looks exactly like the right one in your screenshot (use the drop-down menu for Viewport Shading options for the matcap). This is correct because the normals are smooth. But it's not what you want to bake.

To get a proper bake

- apply the scale the to plane and the cone (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *Apply* > *Scale* in *Object* mode)
- edit the cone, select the top vertex and bevel it a tiny bit (0.1 mm) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- now you can add two or three more support edge loops with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. It's important to place one at the bottom and one at the top. Another can be placed in the middle
  Now you should have a clean shading when your cone is smooth-shaded (in *Object* mode, use the context menu to choose *Shaded Smooth*)
- finally, you can bake it.

For some reason, you will still get a little glitch in the center of the baked normal map no matter how tiny you scale down the top vertices of the cone. I don't know how to fix this with geometry so I've just ended up using the *Smudge* brush and fixed it carefully in *Texture Paint* mode.

Zoomed to the tip of the cone with support edge loop (red):

[image: tip of the cone]

Bottom of the cone with support edge loop:

[image: bottom of the cone]

Baked result (with manually fixed center):

[image: baked normal]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Blunder's input, I came up with another solution.

- 1st started out as a cylinder, then scale 0 on all top vertices (not merged yet) to make a cone shape.
- 2nd, added a bunch edge loops, including one loop near the tip.
- 3rd, merged all top vertices by distance and applied smooth shading and auto smooth normal

This will produces the point tip on the normal.
[image: added edge loops]
[image: edge loop need the tip]
[image: normal with pointy tip]